# How to set a minimum content size of a webpage in html, css?

Tags: html, css

I would like to set a minimum size for the content of a web page, like as it is for example by facebook. So even if the user is minimizing the browsers window, the content wont be shrinking proportionally after a while...

I tried to give min-width to the body in css, but it is not doing anything.

Could you please give a hint? Thank you!

Comment: no that is a typo, i edit the post

Comment: Are you using a responsive css framework like bootstrap because this seems like a trivially easy problem to solve. `.container { width: 900px;}` Please link to some example code.

Comment: now its ok, I gave min width to the header too... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `min-width` of the body/container should do the trick, if it didn't work then you will have to provide us with some of your code so we can see what's going on (a live example would also be very helpful).

Ex:

```
.container{
   min-width: 1300px; /* Should stop downsizing after 1300px */
}
```

Comment: yes, now it works... However I didn't change anything, it must be something very stupid from me... But thanks, and sorry for bothering you. When the 10 minutes are over i accept the answer.

Comment: ahh, ok, what I did: I gave min width to my header too